# Installation decision

Tags: hardware, compatibility

it's my first attempt to install Ubuntu 12.04.4 on my PC. There is already Win7 and WinXP installed. I also have 4 HDD with various partitions. When I used the Windows Installer method, it completed succesfully. After Reboot , i get a grump screen prompt, nothing more. After this it occured to me: what is the correct Ubuntu version for my hardware. The PC is not very old, i5 processor , 4GB RAM, but 32bit. SHould I use 64 or 32 bit installation for Ubuntu?

Thank You

Alex

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing has nothing to do with the choice 32bit / 64 bit - its more that the ubuntu installer overrides the Windows Boatloader - you have to manually take care of it. There are plenty guides out there who deal with that topic. e.g https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

I'd recommended for you though to use 64 bit ubuntu, since the i5 core allows you to and the amount of ram you're currently running is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to point out that I also Installed same Ubuntu version on my laptop which runs Win8.1 . Ofcourse I used the cd-boot installation, but it works nice. and I get a dual boot promt (ubuntu asks, not windows) , so it seems that all runs correct on the laptop. Should I maybe avoid the WindowsInstaller, provide a clean unformated partition to Ubuntu and install from boot-CD?

Comment: please read through the provided guide on help.ubuntu.com - it deals with both possible situations (ubuntu after windows, ubuntu before windows installation). The problem is, you can only have one bootloader in a system - so the ubuntu bootloader has to be configured to know that there is a windows installation out there (see link above)

Answer (score 0):

if you think you have problem with boot loader then boot from live ubuntu cd and go to termianl by ctlr+alt+T  and just use the command below,

**sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)**

this help me whenever i have problem after install ubuntu alongside with windows, 
hope this will help you too. I think you should use 64bit , 4g rem and i5 processor is enough for using 64bit